# GridView equal space distribution

Tags: android, xml, gridview

I am trying to use GridView to show 4 pieces of content. In the code bellow this content is only an ImageView, but a textView will later be added.
I created a 2x2 GridView, and I expected the screen space to be divided equally by all 4 grid cells, but that is not happening. If set to `fill_parent` the cell takes the whole screen (like image bellow), if set to `wrap_content` the cells get pilled up near one of the corners. How can I get the cell to distribute equally using only the XML layout file?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:rowCount="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:columnCount="2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_rowSpan="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_rowSpan="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="0">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_rowSpan="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_rowSpan="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Any reason that you wouldn't just use `LinearLayout` with weights?

Comment: If I have too, I will, but I find that solution not elegant at all, it feels just like brute forcing you way out of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:rowCount="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:columnCount="2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I've removed `layout_height`, `layout_width`, `layout_rowSpan` and `layout_columnSpan` and used the *weight* with `layout_gravity="fill"` instead.

Comment: Just what I needed! Thanks!